# What does whatcha mean?

Tags: contractions

In casual conversations, does *whatcha* mean any one of the following three options depending on contexts?

= what are you
▶ Whatcha gonna do?

= what have you
▶ Whatcha got?

= What do you
▶ Whatcha wanna do now?

Comment: Yes, it can mean all of those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Whatcha" is an *eye dialect* spelling of "What you".

In casual speech the helper verb has completely merged:

So in "What do you" the "d" of do has merged with the "t".  The "o" of do has been reduced to a schwa to form something like "Wo d' ya" and then lost completely and the "y" has merged with the "t/d" to make "ty" or "ch".  "Wotchya" or "Whatcha".

Similarly, the consonants in have and are dropped or merged, and the vowels reduced and lost.

Compare also these eye-spellings

> Whatsee gonna do (What is he going to do)
>
> Whatsee got (what has he got)
>
> Whatsee want (What does he want)

Here the helper verb has been reduced to "s" in each case, and the pronoun "h" has become "ee".

Remember, don't use these eye spellings in written work, except to make a point of emphasising the pronunciation of the speaker.

Comment: In UK, "Whatcha!" is also used as a casual greeting.

Comment: @WeatherVane - usually rendered as 'wotcher' in my experience.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey perhaps – I don't remember ever seeing it written.

Comment: @WeatherVane - wotcher in British English ... a British slang term of greeting (esp in the phrase wotcher cock!) Collins Dictionary; "wotcher 
The definitive cockney salutation, especially in the phrase ‘wotcher cock!’ " - Oxford; "In Alice's very brief appearance in series five episode one, she says just one word to the startled Luther: wotcher." - Radio Times BBC.

Comment: @WeatherVane = frequent in Harry Potter, apparently.

Comment: I get the point. I haven't read Harry Potter, though, which is perhaps why I haven't seen it in print.